# npm run dev won't start server

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to do a "npm run dev", but it's not starting a server. I thought that it was supposed to and open up http://127.0.0.1:8000. How do I get it to do that? "npm start" works and goes to my localhost. I looked for an answer, but couldn't find anything. If anyone can help me out or give me a link to an answer, I'd appreciate it. I'm new here. Thanks. If it helps:

npm -v
6.4.1

node -v
v10.13.0

webpack -v
4.20.2

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "cocos-skeleton",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "private": true,
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "cross-env eslint src",
    "test": "cross-env jest --passWithNoTests",
    "test:watch": "cross-env jest --passWithNoTests --watch --notify",
    "test:coverage": "cross-env jest --coverage",
    "config": "cross-env webpack --config tools/webpack/webpack.config.js",
    "bundle": "cross-env npm run config -- --mode production",
    "bundle:watch": "cross-env npm run config -- --mode development --watch --progress --display-error-details",
    "compile": "cross-env cocos compile",
    "start": "cross-env cocos run",
    "dev": "cross-env npm run bundle:watch & npm run start",
    "refresh": "cross-env npm run compile && npm run start",
    "release": "cross-env cocos run -m release"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "linters": {
      "*.js": [
        "eslint --fix",
        "jest --bail --findRelatedTests",
        "git add"
      ]
    },
    "ignore": [
      "**/frameworks/**/*.js"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
    "howler": "^2.0.15",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "prando": "^3.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-lodash": "^3.3.4",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint": "^5.6.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^13.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "husky": "^1.1.0",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "lint-staged": "^7.3.0",
    "lodash-webpack-plugin": "^0.11.5",
    "prettier-eslint": "^8.8.2",
    "webpack": "^4.20.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "extends": "airbnb-base",
    "globals": {
      "cc": true,
      "ccui": true
    },
    "env": {
      "browser": true,
      "jest": true
    },
    "rules": {
      "func-names": [
        "error",
        "as-needed"
      ],
      "no-console": [
        "error",
        {
          "allow": [
            "warn",
            "error",
            "assert"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "complexity": [
        "error",
        5
      ],
      "max-params": [
        "error",
        5
      ],
      "max-depth": [
        "error",
        4
      ],
      "max-statements": [
        "error",
        20
      ],
      "max-lines-per-function": [
        "error",
        50
      ],
      "max-classes-per-file": [
        "error",
        1
      ],
      "max-nested-callbacks": [
        "error",
        3
      ],
      "max-statements-per-line": [
        "error",
        {
          "max": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "jest": {
    "bail": true,
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "branches": 0,
        "functions": 0,
        "lines": 0,
        "statements": 0
      }
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.js"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^.+\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga|cur)$": "<rootDir>/src/lib/mocks/FileMock.js"
    }
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
          "useBuiltIns": "usage",
          "targets": {
            "ie": "11"
          }
        }
      ]
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ]
  },
  "prettier": {
    "singleQuote": true,
    "trailingComma": "all",
    "printWidth": 100
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const { join } = require('path');
const LodashModuleReplacementPlugin = require('lodash-webpack-plugin');
const { dependencies } = require('../../package.json');
const sourcePath = join(`${__dirname}/../../src`);
module.exports = {
  entry: { main: './src/index.js', vendor: Object.keys(dependencies) },
  optimization: { splitChunks: { name: 'vendor', minChunks: 2 } },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: sourcePath,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: [
            [
              '@babel/preset-env',
              {
                useBuiltIns: 'usage',
                targets: {
                  ie: 11,
                },
              },
            ],
          ],
          plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', 'lodash'],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [new LodashModuleReplacementPlugin()],
};
```

Comment: Sharing `package.json` and webpack config file might be useful.

Comment: do you have a 'dev' string in your scripts section of package.json?

Comment: Wait, localhost equals to `127.0.0.1`, doesn't it?

Comment: This is what I have:  "dev": "cross-env npm run bundle:watch & npm run start". If I do the "npm run start", then it will launch http://127.0.0.1:8000 and open it up in my browser.

Comment: @SlawomirWozniak Yes, localhost = 127.0.0.1. That's not the question that I was asking about. Both 127.0.0.1:8000 and localhost:8000 did not open up for me.

Comment: @Technoman please share the important files in your question. It increases the readability.

Comment: package.json and webpack.config.js files have been added.

Comment: Your `dev` script seem to be missing an ampersand (should be `... && npm run start`, instead of `... & npm run start`. And word of advice: the script syntax is pretty convoluted... all scripts are using `cross-env` without envs (this doesn't do anything), and build scripts are calling each other adding more and more parameters... I wouldn't be surprised there are additional issues because of the depth of command nesting being done. Know that it's ok to create a long command that might be duplicated; it's certainly easier to read and follow than a tree of dependencies in script form.

Answer (score 0):

I think this one might help you
[Difference between npm run dev and npm run production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63133245/difference-between-npm-run-dev-and-npm-run-production)

If you try to build front-end in the server. You could try `npm run build` or `npm run production`. Try it