# why Vue.js is detected on this page. Devtools inspection is not available because it's in production mode or explicitly disabled by the author

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-8

when I run my project, I can't see the changes. Also, I am trying to enable vue-devtools in Google Chrome. But I can't enable it.
the project is built by vue.js inside the Laravel and it runs by php artisan serve.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoQ4r.png)

Comment: Vue dev tools are only enabled when it's compiled in dev mode. When you use the production flag, it's minified and you can't use the devtools

Comment: @aynber yes but how to use development flag, or what I should do to see the changes when I run the project?

Comment: You need to use the `npm` command to compile the assets. Usually `npm run dev` and `npm run prod`  . Your `package.json` might have a few other commands you can run. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63133245/difference-between-npm-run-dev-and-npm-run-production explains a bit about both

Comment: @aynber I did this and the Compiled is done Successfully, but the same problem, I can't see any of changes what I did in the project

Comment: Can you be more specific?  "I can't see any changes".  Do you mean you're running the production build, making a change, and expecting the production build to update itself?  Or do you mean the updated prod build does not include latest changes?  It's not clear.  Also to use dev tools why not just run the project in dev mode? It seems like the appropriate mode for what you're doing.

Comment: @yoduh ok I make some changes.. like I change the header for a page, what the steps that I should do to see the changes on the server when I run it by php artisan serve?

Comment: As for devtools, use "Vue force dev"